# Cloaking parts of URL when force HTTPS in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, https, clean-urls

This question is about:

- Forcing HTTPS
- Keep/make the URL tidy
- Catch all calls to be directed to a routing file

Before I had SSL on my site, I had a RewriteRule like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /directory/file.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

which forced all requests to go to the file.php in /directory/ but the URL looked like (which was lovely):

```
http://example.com
```

so that all the /argument/argument2/argument3 etc could be added after the URL to be picked up as parameters in file.php and be handled, like this:

```
$args = array_filter(
    explode("/", htmlspecialchars($_GET["url"])), function($value) { return $value !== ''; }
);
```

Then I added this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/directory/file.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

in hope that the URL should look like this and point to the same file:

```
https://www.example.com/
```

but now the URL looks like this:

```
https://www.example.com/directory/file.php?url=index.html
```

It did not just change to https and added the /directory/file.php?url=, it also added index.html to the URL.

The full rewrite looks like this all together:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/directory/file.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

---

*Edited:*

**So i fixed it by doing**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "/directory/file.php?url=$1" [NC,L,QSA]
```